# How to change date format with two files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have two tables and want to use pandas to transpose them into one table that looks exactly like this. The order has to be the same and the dates the exactly same format.

My table1.csv

```
Tweet, Month, Day, Year
Hello World, 6, 2, 2013
I want ice-cream!, 7, 23, 2013
Friends will be friends, 9, 30, 2017
Done with school, 12, 12, 2017
```

My table2.csv

```
Month, Day, Year, Hour, Tweet
January, 2, 2015, 12, Happy New Year
March, 21, 2016, 7, Today is my final
May, 30, 2017, 23, Summer is about to begin
July, 15, 2018, 11, Ocean is still cold
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

from datetime import *


df1=pd.read_csv('data1.csv', index_col=False, header=0)

df2=pd.read_csv('data2.csv', index_col=False, header=0)

#creating Date column from Day,Month and Year columns
df1['Date']= df1.apply(lambda x:datetime.strptime("{0} {1} {2}"
                .format(x['Year'],x['Month'], x['Day']), "%Y %m %d"),axis=1)



df2['Date']= df2.apply(lambda x:datetime.strptime("{0} {1} {2}"
                .format(x['Year'],x['Month'], x['Day']), "%Y %B %d"),axis=1)

#Selecting only desired columns
df1=df1[['Date','Tweet']]
df2=df2[['Date','Tweet']]

#combining both data frames
combine=df1.append(df2)

#Sort the data frame based on Date column.
combine.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False, inplace=True)

#convert date to required format
combine['Date'] = combine['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%b-%Y')

#writing to csv
combine.to_csv('combine.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

This is the output I got:

```
Date,Tweet

07-Jul-2018,Ocean is still cold

12-Dec-2017,Done with school

09-Sep-2017,Friends will be friends

05-May-2017,Summer is about to begin

03-Mar-2016,Today is my final

01-Jan-2015,Happy New Year

07-Jul-2013,I want ice-cream!

06-Jun-2013,Hello World
```

Clearly, the day is completely wrong, anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: [Please don't post your code or data as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). There is no way to copy and paste a picture into a code editor. So it will be much harder, and thus less likely, for someone to help. To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you sir, I will remember to do that next time

Answer (score 3):

Can't you simply

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']])
df2['Month'] = df2.Month.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%B').month)
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']])

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])[['Date','Tweet']]
```

E.g.:

```
s1 = '''Tweet,Month,Day,Year
Hello World,6,2,2013'''
s2 = '''Month,Day,Year,Hour,Tweet
January,2,2015,12,Happy New Year'''
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s1))
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s2))

In []:
from datetime import datetime
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']])
df2['Month'] = df2['Month'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%B').month)
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']])
pd.concat([df1, df2])[['Date', 'Tweet']]

Out[]:
        Date           Tweet
0 2013-06-02     Hello World
0 2015-01-02  Happy New Year

In []:
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])[['Date', 'Tweet']].sort_values('Date', ascending=False)
df['Date'] = df.Date.dt.strftime('%d-%b-%y'))
df

Out[]:
        Date           Tweet
0  02-Jan-15  Happy New Year
0  02-Jun-13     Hello World
```

Comment: It would help if you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is easy to test.

Comment: I noticed you have long form months in `df2`, added a conversion to number.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, all I want is to keep the last two digit in the year and have the correct dates. The correct data table is sorted, do you know how to sort it?

Comment: `'January'` vs `1` - you should have enough above to sort out your remaining issues.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `pd.to_datetime` on `df1`s relevant columns
- Stitch year, month, date together as a string then pass to `pd.to_datetime` for `df2`
- Use `pd.concat` to put join
- Use `assign` and a `lambda` to overwrite `Date` column with a formatted string

---

```
pd.concat([
    df1[['Tweet']].assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df1.drop('Tweet', 1))),
    df2[['Tweet']].assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(
        [f'{y}-{m}-{d}' for _, m, d, y, *_ in df2.itertuples()]))
])[['Date', 'Tweet']].assign(Date=lambda d: d.Date.dt.strftime('%d-%b-%y'))

        Date                     Tweet
0  02-Jun-13               Hello World
1  23-Jul-13         I want ice-cream!
2  30-Sep-17   Friends will be friends
3  12-Dec-17          Done with school
0  02-Jan-15            Happy New Year
1  21-Mar-16         Today is my final
2  30-May-17  Summer is about to begin
3  15-Jul-18       Ocean is still cold
```